# PYTHON Add the contents of a string variable to the beginning of a function?

Tags: python, function, variables, object

So what I have here is one function, which is in an object:

```
class objectOne:  
    def funct1(self):
        #Do Stuff
```

And what I would like to do is have it so when I create two instaces of the object:

```
dog = objectOne()

cat = objectOne()
```

When the variable "animal" i have created contains cat, then it would run:

```
cat.funct1()
```

And when the variable contains dog, then it would run:

```
dog.funct1()
```

Any way to do this? Thanks in advance guys.

Ev :D

(To clarify: I can't use an if statement here because as I gain more and more different instances of the object, I don't want to have to add stuff, my final code to call the object's function should be something like:

```
animal.funct1()
```

In which animal is the variable, not an instance of the object. Thanks once again guys!)

Comment: That's how it **does** work. If you do `animal = cat`, then whenever you do `animal.funct1()` you will be calling the method on the cat instance.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'd guess he meant that the `animal` would contain the name of the object (`animal = 'cat'`). At least that's how I understood it from `the variable "animal" i have created contains cat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). Animals will be keys, objects will be items.

Example:

```
animals = {}
animals['cat'] = objectOne()
animal = 'cat'
animals[animal].funct1()
```